# Solving 2nd order ODE, Matlab- the acceleration in the equation needs its own value in order to include another different term

Tags: matlab, position, ode, acceleration

I have this 2nd order ODE to solve in Matlab:

```
(a + f(t))·(dx/dt)·(d²x/dt²)  +  g(t)  +  ((h(t) + i(t)·(d²x/dt² > b·(c-x)))·(dx/dt)  +  j(t))·(dx/dt)²  +  k(t)·(t > d)  = 0
```

where

- `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` are known constants
- `f(t)`,`g(t)`,`h(t)`,`i(t)`,`j(t)`,`k(t)` are known functions dependent on `t`
- `x` is the position
- `dx/dt` is the velocity
- `d²x/dt²` is the acceleration

and notice the two conditions that

- `i(t)` is introduced in the equation if `(d²x/dt² > b·(c-x))`
- `k(t)` is introduced in the equation if `(t > d)`

So, the problem could be solved with a similar structure in Matlab as this example:

```
[T,Y] = ode45(@(t,y) [y(2); 'the expression of the acceleration'], tspan, [x0 v0]);
```

where

- `T` is the time vector,  `Y` is the vector of position (column 1 as `y(1)`) and velocity (column 2 as `y(2)`).
- `ode45` is the ODE solver, but another one could be used.
- `tspan`,`x0`,`v0` are known.
- `the expression of the acceleration` means an expression for `d²x/dt²`, but **here comes the problem, since it is inside the condition for `i(t)` and 'outside' at the same time multiplying `(a + f(t))·(dx/dt)`**. So, the acceleration cannot be written in matlab as `d²x/dt² = something`

Some issues that could help:

- once the condition `(d²x/dt² > b·(c-x))` and/or `(t > d)` is satisfied, the respective term `i(t)` and/or `k(t)` will be introduced until the end of the determined time in `tspan`.
- for the condition `(d²x/dt² > b·(c-x))`, the term `d²x/dt²` could be written as the difference of velocities, like `y(2) - y(2)'`, if `y(2)'` is the velocity of the previous instant, divided by the step-time defined in `tspan`. But I do not know **how to access the previous value of the velocity *during* the solving of the ODE**

Thank you in advanced !

Comment: You could try an implicit solver, such as [`ode15i`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode15i.html)

Comment: @Steve: And what will that solve?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft That solves the fact that this is an implicit ODE, where `x_tt := d^2x/dt^2` is *effectively* an implicit argument as `H(x_tt - b(c*x))` where `H(t)` is the Heaviside step function `H(t) = 1 if t>=0, 0 if t<0`. Whether the solution exists or makes sense is another issue to look in to.

Comment: Actually what I've said is not quite right, because of your condition *once the condition [...] is satisfied, the respective [terms] will be introduced until the end of the determined time*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should [reduce your problem to a first-order differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Reduction_of_order), by substituting dx/dt with a dynamical variable for the velocity.
This is something you have to do anyway for solving the ODE and this way you do not need to access the previous values of the velocity.

As for realising your conditions, just modify the function you pass to `ode45` to account for this.
For this purpose you can use that d²x/dt² is in the right-hand side of your ODE.
Keep in mind though that ODE solvers do not like discontinuities, so you may want to smoothen the step or just restart the solver with a different function, once the condition is met (credit to [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5358968/steve)).

Comment: I agree completely with the first paragraph, but regarding the second, `ode45` relys on that you can express the equation in terms of the highest order derivative, which is not possible due to the `i(t)*(x_tt>b(c-x))*x_t*x_tt` term

Comment: You cannot explicitly evaluate that condition anyway since it stays once it’s switched on and you have to rely on the absence of paradox anyway. (Also see my edit.)

Comment: +1 Okay that makes more sense to me now. I've started writing up the "restart the solver with a different function" part, so I'll finish and post that, but this answer seems to have covered it.

Comment: You should use *events* to find the points to restart the integration, using 0-1-constants that are changed during an event instead of having the locigal conditions inside the ODE function. That way the integration is smooth and can reliably find the end points of each segment.

Comment: @JRM: Please read the documentation and try implementing this yourself (ask a follow-up question if you encounter problems). I don’t speak Matlab.

Comment: See new answer @Wrzlprmft

Comment: @JRM: There is no new answer. If you want to self-answer your question, that’s fine, but please post an actual answer and do not edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

The second conditional term `k(t)*(t>d)` should be simple enough to implement, so I'll pass over that.

I would split up your equation into two part:

```
F1(t,x,x',x'') := (a+f(t))x'x'' + g(t) + (h(t)x'+j(t))x'' + k(t)(t>d),
F2(t,x,x',x'') := F1(t,x,x',x'') + i(t)x'x'',
```

where prime denote time derivatives. As suggested in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46401287/5358968)

> [...] or just restart the solver with a different function

you could solve the ODE `F1` for `t \in [t0, t1] =: tspan`. Next, you'd find the first time `tstar` where `x''> b(c-x)` and the values `x(tstar)` and `x'(tstar)`, and solve `F2` for `t \in [tstar,t1]` with `x(tstar), x'(tstar)` as starting conditions.

Having said all that, the proper implementation of this should be using [*events*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/ode-event-location.html), as suggested in [LutzL's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46395063/solving-2nd-order-ode-matlab-the-acceleration-in-the-equation-needs-its-own-va/46402018#comment79761235_46401287).

Answer (score 0):

So, I should use something that looks like this:

```
function [value,isterminal,direction] = ODE_events(t,y,b,c)

value = d²x/dt² - b*(c-y(1));   % detect (d²x/dt² > b·(c-x)), HOW DO I WRITE d²x/dt² HERE?
isterminal = 0;                 % continue integration
direction  = 0;                 % zero can be approached in either direction
```

and then include in the file (.m), where my ode is, this:

```
refine = 4; % I do not get exactly how this number would affect the results
options = odeset('Events',@ODE_events,'OutputFcn',@odeplot,'OutputSel',1, 'Refine',refine);

[T,Y] = ode45(@(t,y) [y(2); ( 1/(a + f(t))*(y(2)))*( - g(t) - ((h(t) + i(t))·(y(2))  -  j(t)·(y(2))² - k(t)*(t > d))  ], tspan, [x0 v0], options);
```

How do I handle `i(t)`? because `i(t)*(d²x/dt² > b*(c-y(1))))*(y(2))` has to be included somehow.

Thank you again